# Java PriorityQueue

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am trying to implement PriorityQueue. This PriorityQueue is going to hold instances of class Task. These instances of Task should be arranged in such a way that the instances which have higher "priority" are at the head of the Queue. In short, instances should be in descending order of priority.

```
    private static Queue<Task> testQ = new PriorityQueue<Task>(11, new TaskQueueComparator());


    /*** Comparator ***/        
    public class TaskQueueComparator implements Comparator<Task> {

    public int compare(Task task1, Task task2) {
        return task2.priority - task1.priority;
        }        
    }

    /**** Task definition **/       
    public class Task {
        public int priority;
        }


    /**** Code in main() ****/

    Task pe11 = new Task();
    pe11.priority = 3;
    testQ.add(pe11);


    pe11 = new Task();
    pe11.priority = 1;
    testQ.add(pe11);


    pe11 = new Task();
    pe11.priority = 2;
    testQ.add(pe11);


    void displayQueue() {

    int size = testQ.size();

    for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        Task p = testQ.poll();
        System.out.format("Task Priority %d \n", p.priority); // The result I am getting is  3 1 2.. I was expecting 3 2 1
    }
```

As shown in the comment, this outputs 3,1,2 instead of 3,2,1 like I was expecting. Can someone please let me know what mistake I am doing here ? Every time I remove or add a task from /to the queue, the queue should arrange the tasks in descending order of priority.

Let me know.

Thanks
Josh

Comment: What is going wrong? You said what it should do, but what is it doing?

Comment: Homework? Or is there a reason not to use java.util.PriorityQueue?

Comment: I was given the impression that the OP *is* using java.util.PriorityQueue, because otherwise we'd need to see the implementations of add() (and probably poll()). If he isn't, we need to see more of the code.

Comment: I get minus 1 for reading comprehension then!

Comment: Also, what happens if you create the Task elements all at once, *then* insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, PriorityQueue only returns the elements in priority order when you poll() the Queue. I found this one out the hard way when I tired iterating over it a long time ago. Additionally, it only performs the compare on insertion. So if your priority changes while in the queue you are going to get very odd behavior.

By changing your code to the following:

```
void displayQueue() {
    while (!testQ.isEmpty())
    {   
    Task p = testQ.poll(); // poll, you want to remove the head
    System.out.format("Task Priority %d \n", p.priority);
    }
}
```

I was able to get:

Task Priority 3

Task Priority 2

Task Priority 1

Comment: Shouldn't replacing `peek` with `poll` in the original code produce the same behavior?

Comment: peek will only return the head, which is 3. The original code only displays 3, 3, 3.

Comment: I am aware. That's why I asked if simply changing the original code to call `poll` instead also fixes the problem.

Comment: Sorry, misread. It won't because poll removes the item and that reduces the size of the queue. Since he looping based on size, the size will change per iteration.

Comment: No, because he stores the original size in a local variable and uses that.

Comment: The value of size does not change, but the size of the Queue will change as he is iterating if he uses poll().

Comment: Sure, but how is that different from this?

Comment: Just a coding style, at the end of the day it will produce the same result just by simply changing peek to poll. Now I feel silly because I realize what you were asking :(

Comment: It's fine. Still not sure how OP is getting 3-1-2 though.

Comment: Thanks the for explanation. I was watching queue at the debug time and elements were not arranged by higher priority but you are right when you poll, the elements were returned correctly. Thanks to all others who mentioned about the poll method. There were so many places in my code where I was using testQ.remove(object) instead of simple poll(), that was messing up my logic too. Thanks everyone. It was hard for me to figure out which should be marked as right answer.. because most of you did point me in right direction. I am marking this as answer because of most descriptive explanation.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. The thing about PriorityQueues is that they don't have to keep everything in order internally; they only have to be able to spit out the elements in the correct order when removing from the "head" of the queue. What probably happened was that while in debug, you saw what the PriorityQueue had internally. (I think in debug you see the result of calling toString(), but I could be wrong)

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought your Comparator might not be doing the right thing with "ProcessElements" but it looks like that was a typo.

This returns "3 3 3" for me, as is..

Did you mean to .poll() and not peek()?

Comment: Sorry my bad.. it should be poll and not peek.